# Using property file in hibernate mapping

Tags: hibernate, properties, hibernate-mapping

I have a two nodes environment using the
same database. In the database there
is a resource table like

RESOURCE_ID,

CODE,

NODE

The content of the NODE column can be 1 or 2 depending on which node can use it.
As I need to deploy the same ear to the two nodes, I would like to map this table like this:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="ResourceVO" table="RESOURCE"
           dynamic-update="true" optimistic-lock="dirty" where="NODE=${node.value}" >
```

I would like to store the node.value property on the file system, so the instances could identify which resource to use.
Is it possible in hibernate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, Hibernate doesn't offer any support for this and I would personally use a build tool (Ant, Maven) here, they both have filtering capabilities. See for example the chapter [9.3. Resource Filtering](http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-description.html) in the Maven Book for Maven.